# Animating two objects rotating around a common axis with a driver affecting one of the objects

Tags: animation, transforms, drivers

I have two objects. Object A has a driver that causes Object B to translate in the Z direction when Object A is rotated around its Z axis.

I want to rotate both objects together around a common axis, when I do, Object A rotates as expected but Object B follows an elliptical path (I assume because of the additive effects of the rotation and the driver).

How do I get it to rotate as expected? How do I do it when animating when I want Object B to rotate around the common axis but still translate in the Z direction with Z axis rotation of Object A?

Answer (score 0):

just animate the "delta transform" values instead the transform values, where the driver is.

[image]